# Flutter | How to always keep Text Field in focus(Keep show cursor)

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Here, I've one text field which I want to keep always in focus and I don't want to open keyboard when the text field is clicked. in short text field always needs to be in focus.

Here is the my text field code.

```
TextFormField(
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.white,
    fontSize: orientation == Orientation.portrait
      ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.030
      : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.020,
  ),
  validator: (val) => Validators.validateRequired(
    val, " Product Baarcode"
  ),
  controller: _addproduct,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    errorStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow),
    enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
    ),
    fillColor: Colors.white,
    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
    ),
    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    filled: false,
    prefixIcon: Icon(
      FontAwesomeIcons.barcode,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
    labelText: "Enter Product Barcode",
    hintText: "Enter Product Barcode",
  ),
  onFieldSubmitted: (val) {
    _addProduct();
  },
),
```

Comment: What else is there apart from the TextField? This can be achieved with FocusNodes but we need to know what other Widgets you have in the same view.

Comment: The combination of wanting focus on a TextFormField but not wanting the keyboard to show up is tricky. Typically you hide the keyboard by shifting focus away to an empty FocusNode. But that will also remove focus from the TextFormField. Could you please share why you want to do this?

Comment: Hello, @JoãoSoares thank you for your answer I need this because I've text field in this text field I have a scanner attached when I scan the product it will automatically fill the barcode inside the text field. so that's why I don't need a keyboard because my text field is going to automatically fill. and I want to always focus text field because  scanning product happen anytime.

Comment: If i understood your explanation correctly, then I'd like to know why you want to use a TextField at all? Are there more TextFields on the same view? Do you have a screenshot you can share to help visualise what you want to achieve?

Comment: can you suggest anything else instead of a text field that I can use??

Comment: I can. But it would be helpful if you shared a screenshot of your view, to help us understand.

Comment: Based on your code it looks like you just want a FlatButton that changes its text content to the code that you scan from the barcode. Or is the user supposed to enter the code manually? This will determine what kind of widget we can use.

Comment: Would like to know if you had a chance to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the autofocus property to true so that the cursor will start showing as soon as the app starts.

[For more info please refer to this link](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/focus)

```
TextField(
  autofocus: true,
)
```